# Make SCL library avaiable system wide on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, libraries

I have softwares asking for some libraries

- `libstdc++.so.6` version `C++ABI_1.3.8` and
- `libomp.so.5`

I've found out that the first one comes with `devtoolset-7` and the second one comes with the `llvm-toolset-7`, so I've installed both from the SCL repository, but when I use the command:

```shell
scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
scl enable llvm-toolset-7 bash
```

They're only working in that current terminal session and not on the system.

How can I make these libraries available on the system?